# Generate a nonce with Apache 2.4 (for a Content Security Policy header)

Tags: apache, security, content-security-policy

We're working on creating a strict Content Security Policy (https://csp.withgoogle.com/docs/strict-csp.html) which necessitates Apache creating a nonce each time a resource is requested, so that we can insert this nonce into the http header.

How can we create a nonce with Apache 2.4?

All of the CSP related documentation I've read says something to the effect of "A nonce is just a random string that's generated on the server, included in the CSP header..." but haven't found any info on how to do this with Apache. We could of course do this with app code, but doing it via Apache seems like a cleaner solution/will ensure every single page gets the CSP header.

Answer (score 6):

You need to generate the `nonce` on the server, and then have Apache pass that `nonce` to your script where it can be used.

We've created an open source module for Apache that simplifies this process: **[mod_cspnonce](https://github.com/wyday/mod_cspnonce)**.

Here's a simple example of the server-side config:

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule cspnonce_module modules/mod_cspnonce.so

# add the CSP_NONCE to the "default-src"
Header add Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' 'nonce-%{CSP_NONCE}e';"
```

Here's a simple example of using the nonce in your script:

```
<script nonce="<?= $_SERVER['CSP_NONCE'] ?>">
  var inline = 1;
</script>
```

That example is php, but you can use any language.

Comment: Do we have an example for Angular with httpd.

Comment: Nope. Use your favorite search engine to see how to use server-set variables in your scripts.

Answer (score 3):

After finding mod_unique_id, this was very easy (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_unique_id.html).

1.) Enable mod_unique_id. This is generally one line in httpd.conf:
LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so

2.) mod_unique_id generates a unique string (see user3526609's answer, this may or may not be random enough for you) and server variable UNIQUE_ID set equal to that random string, on each page request, which you can then inject into your CSP and any inline code you need to whitelist. If you happen to use Php, $_SERVER['UNIQUE_ID'];

Answer (score 3):

I would have preferred to simply add this as a comment but my reputation <50 does not allow it so I'm posting this as an answer instead.

In response to:

> 1.) apache generates a random string via mod_unique_id

This is a "unique" value not a "random" value, so you might want to be careful with its use as a CSP nonce.

> 2.) we insert this into our CSP header (not sure how to do this actually)

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$">
        Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-%{UNIQUE_ID}e' 'unsafe-inline' ' https:;
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks yes "random" is a very strong word that should rarely be used, I edited my answer. And thanks for the example, that's exactly right.

Comment: Unfortunately, strings generated by mod_unique_id may have '@' characters, which browsers don't allow as part of CSP nonce. Since '@' character doesn't appear always, sites using this technique break randomly.

Answer (score 1):

In Apache you must have module called mod_unique_id enabled. He generates a unique environment variable (UNIQUE_ID). However, its encoding has illegal characters for csp [A-Za-z0-9@-] instead of the usual base64 [A-Za-z0-9+/].

You should use base64 encoding to generate proper values. For example:

```
Header set X-Nonce "expr=%{base64:%{reqenv:UNIQUE_ID}}"
```

Then to generate complete CSP policy do:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "expr=default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-%{base64:%{reqenv:UNIQUE_ID}}'"
```

In PHP use:

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_X_NONCE'];
```

to extract nonce.

Comment: Unique ID does not use cryptographically secure random number generators. It just uses the current time (which is guessable and thus exploitable). See my answer above.

Comment: @WyattO'Day yes. cspnonce you proposed is best way, unfortunately my hosting company did not wanted to install this extension (dont know why but they use only default modules for Apache), so this is second best thing.

Comment: If malicious actors can guess the CSP nonce (which they can if you use Unique ID) then there is absolutely no point in using the CSP. Either switch to a hosting provider that actually supports security, or disable fake security.

Answer (score 0):

The nonce has to be inserted into any element with inline CSS and/or Javascript handlers, so it has to be inserted at the application layer.

Parsing your output HTML and inserting nonces would defeat the whole purpose of CSP nonces -- the web server has no way of knowing if inline CSS/JS was supposed to be present, or if it was inserted by an attacker.

Comment: In Apache you can `SetEnv VARIABLE_NAME variable_value` to define server variables which can be used at the application layer though. Likewise, nonces in Nginx: https://scotthelme.co.uk/csp-nonce-support-in-nginx/

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if I understand your point about parsing HTML, but mod_unique_id seems like it might do the trick? 1.) apache generates a random string via mod_unique_id, and creates an environment variable named UNIQUE_ID 2.) we insert this into our CSP header (not sure how to do this actually) 3.) in our application code add the nonce where needed, in php that would be via $_SERVER['UNIQUE_ID']   

Does this seem safe? I'm not sure if I full understand your point about parsing html/inserting nonces. Thanks

Comment: @KayakinKoder That seems overly complicated. It'll be much easier to generate a nonce in your application, and insert it into a header yourself. No need to get the web server involved.

Comment: We currently create our CSP in apache, so this was the only way to go for now, although we may move our CSP generation to application code in the near future.

Comment: Just a follow up, we did end up moving our CSP to our application code, which makes it easier to update. @duskwuff was right :) Once we get our entire site updated to be able to handle Google's suggested Strict CSP v3, we may move it back to the server for double-extra-secret security

Answer (score 0):

my apologies but why don't you use randomAlphanumeric(int count)
'nonce-%{base64:randomAlphanumeric(45)}'
maybe is an stupid idea but may help