# HTML5 meta tags: if you remove a security meta tag, does the browser update accordingly?

Tags: html, security

If I have a CSP meta tag (as opposed to using an HTTP header), like so:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src https://cdn.example.net; child-src 'none'; object-src 'none'">`

... and then I go into developer tools and remove that node, would the browser act as though it was never provided, or would the fact that it was added at all be persistent no matter what?

I'm asking because I want to know if I should use an HTTP header (which can't be modified), or if it's safe to just use this meta tag.

Comment: What do you mean by HTTP headers can't be modified?

Comment: @KayakinKoder Specifically once you've loaded a page. When you check the network tab, the request headers are read-only.

Comment: Ah, so you were wondering about security aspect, e.g. a user inspecting the page and editing the CSP? If a user were to do that, they're obviously trying to do something malicious anyway, and you probably wouldn't care if they make themselves prone to XSS :)  Black hat hackers have completely custom-built browsers that can editing anything browser-side, so that's not something I'd worry about.

Comment: Actually I want to add the headers myself, but I am aware that I can also add the meta tag. The meta tag is much easier to add because it requires no server-side code to add headers to the response writer, but I was just wondering if it's safe to use the meta tag.

Comment: Makes sense. The better option when you don't want or can't use server-side code imo is to use your server itself to add the header. Of course adding headers with your server is a bit more difficult initially than inserting a simple meta tag, but especially if you use strict CSP proposed by Google, your CSP should never really change. If you happen to use Apache, this has an example of how to create a header and how I generate a nonce: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43948335/generate-a-nonce-with-apache-2-4-for-a-content-security-policy-header

Answer (score 2):

No. In the [Content Security Policy spec](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#meta-element) it says:

> Note: **Modifications** to the `content` attribute of a `meta` element after the element has been parsed **will be ignored**.  [own markup]

I would read that as: "Once the `meta` tag's CSP is parsed, modifications to the tag (including deletions) will not effect the CSP".

But also note [KayakinKoder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45021244/9358694) and make sure to place the `meta` tag at the very top of the `head` element:

> Authors are strongly encouraged to place meta elements as early in the document as possible, because policies in meta elements are not applied to content which precedes them. In particular, note that resources fetched or prefetched using the Link HTTP response header field, and resources fetched or prefetched using link and script elements which precede a meta-delivered policy will not be blocked.

Answer (score 1):

I definitely wouldn't put it in html. Even if you tell browsers to never cache thing X, some will eventually screw around and cache thing X "to be helpful". Lets say you want to change your CDN from example.net to differentcdn.com in the future; if any browsers have cached your CSP, your site will be broken. Or even worse, you accidentally edit the CSP CDN section to "exEmple.net" and deploy; browsers cache this, and your site is completely broken. We've had some users browsers cache 302 (temporary..) redirects that were clumsily put in an .htaccess file rather than completely server-controlled http.conf, what a nightmare; I don't trust browsers to do what they are supposed to do on anything extremely important that would break our app.

As far as I'm aware, headers are never cached.

Finally, I would recommend looking into Google's strict CSP 3: https://csp.withgoogle.com/docs/strict-csp.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this `Content-Security-Policy` meta tag is "protected", i.e. the browser remembers its value even when it is removed via dev tools.

You can simply try it with this simple example:
index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src self;">
```

Then open dev tools and type in:

```
fetch('http://example.com')
```

You will see something like:

```
VM345:1 Refused to connect to 'http://example.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src self 'mocky.io'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Let's try it with removing that particular meta tag

```
document.querySelector("[http-equiv='Content-Security-Policy']").remove()
fetch('http://example.com')
```

You will still see the same error.

I tried it in the most recent versions of chrome and firefox. Maybe some least known browsers or lower versions will react differently. Unfortunately, I couldn't find more info about it but I don't see any particular reason for not using it.