# Where to declare content security policy report-uri?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, reporting, content-security-policy

I'm new to Content-Security-Policy and first time trying to implement CSP to my Web App, but I've no clue on where to put / declare the report-uri, as it can not be declared using meta http-equiv.

I've tried putting this code in the very top line of my .htaccess file but it seems it doesn't run the URI.

`Header set Content-Security-Policy "report-uri http://localhost/my-webapp-name/report-parser.php"`

but if I POST something manually to 'report-parser.php', the script works just fine.

**Update:**
It Seems I have found the problem but still not found the solution. The problem to my understanding is the policy that I set on .htaccess is overwritten with the policy that I declare inside html `<head></head>` using meta http-equiv.

So the questions become, Where to declare the policy report-uri so that it does not overwritten by the other policy inside the html head?

Comment: can you post your html head code

Comment: nothing fancy inside the html head only <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'">

Comment: https://gist.github.com/phpdave/24d879514e7411047267

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715989/how-to-implement-content-security-policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working solution so far, base on this link https://gist.github.com/phpdave/24d879514e7411047267 shared by Dipak cahvda, is to put all policy in php header() function.